# How to scan for multiple integers and store them in an array?

Tags: assembly, scanf, x86-64

I'm new in assembly and we have this activity that we have to find the minimum number in an array given user input. Our instructor gave as a sample code regarding arrays in assembly so I started there and modified a few parts and I seem to be stuck specifically in storing user input in the array. The code looks like this:

```
;   array = create (size);
create:
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
imul    rdi, 4
call    malloc
leave
ret

;   fill (array, size);
fill:
.array  equ     0
.size   equ     8
.i      equ     16
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 32
    mov     [rsp+.array], rdi
    mov     [rsp+.size], rsi
    xor     ecx, ecx
.more   mov     [rsp+.i], rcx
```

I get a segmentation fault dump right here when it starts scanning for inputs

```
    mov rax,0
    mov rdi,scanner
    mov rsi, input
    call scanf
```

the rest of the code:

```
    mov     rcx, [rsp+.i]
    mov     rdi, [rsp+.array]
    mov     [rdi+rcx*4], eax
    inc     rcx
    cmp     rcx, [rsp+.size]
    jl      .more
    leave
    ret

;   print (array, size);
print:
.array  equ     0
.size   equ     8
.i      equ     16
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 32
        mov     [rsp+.array], rdi
        mov     [rsp+.size], rsi
        xor     ecx, ecx
        mov     [rsp+.i], rcx
        segment .data
.format:
        db      "%10d", 0x0a, 0
        segment .text
.more   lea     rdi, [.format]
        mov     rdx, [rsp+.array]
        mov     rcx, [rsp+.i]
        mov     esi, [rdx+rcx*4]
        mov     [rsp+.i], rcx
        call    printf
        mov     rcx, [rsp+.i]
        inc     rcx
        mov     [rsp+.i], rcx
        cmp     rcx, [rsp+.size]
        jl      .more
        leave
        ret

;   x = min (array, size);
min:
        mov     eax, [rdi]
        mov     rcx, 1
.more   mov     r8d, [rdi+rcx*4]
        cmp     r8d, eax
        cmovl   eax, r8d
        inc     rcx
        cmp     rcx, rsi
        jl      .more
        ret

main:
.array  equ     0
.size   equ     8

        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16

; set default size
    mov ecx, 5
    mov [rsp+.size], rcx

; check for argv[1] providing a size
    cmp edi, 2
    jl .nosize
    mov rdi, [rsi+8]
    call atoi
    mov [rsp+.size], rax

.nosize:

; create the array
    mov rdi, [rsp+.size]
    call create
    mov [rsp+.array], rax

; fill the array with user input
    mov rdi, rax
    mov rsi, [rsp+.size]
    call fill

; if size <= 20 print the array
    mov rsi, [rsp+.size]
    cmp rsi, 20
    jg .toobig
    mov rdi, [rsp+.array]
    call print

.toobig:
; print the minimum
    segment .data

.format:
    db "min: %ld", 0xa, 0
    segment .text
    mov rdi, [rsp+.array]
    mov rsi, [rsp+.size]
    call min
    lea rdi, [.format]
    mov rsi, rax
    call printf

    leave
    ret
```

Comment: You left out the part of your source where you define the `input` label, and reserve space for it (assuming it's a static array).  Same for `scanner`.  So this isn't a [mcve].  Also, what address does `scanf` fault on?

Comment: Don't forget to zero eax before calling `printf`, too.  (preferably with `xor eax,eax`).